# How to change default pastie indicator icon?

Tags: 11.10

How to converted pastie indicator (color one) to look same as regular Ubuntu indicators (gray). I use Ubuntu 11.10.

Answer (score 1):

Answer quoted from [here](http://notsnippets.tumblr.com/post/779328742/how-to-change-the-pastie-icon-in-0-4-5):

If you place the icon you desire to use in `~/.pastie/`, the program should use it.
If there isn’t any icon there, pastie will default to `gtk-paste`.

The icon in `~/.pastie/` should be named `pastie.svg` (“svg” can be any other kind of usable type of image), though.